# Evaluating a cubic polynomial at equally spaced positions

Tags: polynomials

I'm working with somebody else's code, and have come across a method that evaluates a cubic polynomial at equally spaced positions quite efficiently. However, I have no idea why this works mathematically. I suspect it has something to do with forward/backward differences, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
# Polynomial is f(x) = A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D
# x0 is current position, points are spaced at dx beyond x0
# xi = x0 + i*dx

# Setup:
x = x0
xval = x0
val = ((A * x + B) * x + C) * x + D
x -= dx
t2 = ((A * x + B) * x + C) * x + D
x -= dx
t3 = ((A * x + B) * x + C) * x + D
c3 = val - 2 * t2 + t3
c2 = val - t2
cdx = 6 * A * dx**3
# val now stores f(x0)
# xval now stores x0

# To advance to the next position:
c3 += cdx
c2 += c3
val += c2
xval += dx
# val now stores f(x0 + dx), xval stores x0 + dx
# Apply as many times as desired
```

I further suspect that whatever method was used to generate this code also works for higher order polynomials. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: ah thats slick!

Comment: is (dx**3) = $(dx)^3$? @Jolyon

Comment: Expand $f(x+dx)-f(x)=a(x+dx)^3+b(x+dx)^2+c(x+dx) + d - (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ and collect the powers of $x$.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Yes, dx**3 = (dx)^3.

Comment: @dxiv I can do that, but the resulting equation bears little resemblance to anything implemented in this code.

Comment: Following up on the previous comment, I can do the algebra to see that c2 contains the difference required for the first dx. It's the subsequent steps that are nontrivial.

Comment: @Jolyon $c_2$ is the backward difference $f(x)-f(x-dx)$ and $c_3$ is the [$2^{nd}$ order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) backward difference $c_3=f(x)-2 f(x-dx)+ f(x-2dx)\,$. For example `c3 += cdx` means that $c_3(x+dx) = c_3(x) + 6\,A\,dx^3\,$, which can be easily verified algebraically (and it does indeed generalize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $f(x)$ for the cubic polynomial and writing $h$ instead of `dx`, the algorithm is defining
$$
\begin{align}
c_2(x)&:=f(x)-f(x-h)\\
c_3(x)&:=f(x)-2f(x-h)+f(x-2h)\\
c_4(x)&:=6Ah^3
\end{align}
$$
where I've written $c_4(x)$ in place of the (constant) `cdx`. You can check that
$$
\begin{align}
c_2(x+h)&=f(x+h)-f(x)\\
c_3(x+h)&=c_2(x+h)-c_2(x)\\
c_4(x+h)&=c_3(x+h)-c_3(x)
\end{align}\tag1
$$ so the $c$'s are in fact *backward finite differences* for $f$.

Now suppose that you've calculated $f$, $c_2$, $c_3$ at point $x$, and you want the value of $f$ at $x+h$. Note that $c_4$ is constant, so the last equation in (1) is saying that you update $c_3$ for the point $x+h$ by adding $c_4$ to the previous value for $c_3$; the middle equation in (1) is saying you update $c_2$ for the point $x+h$ by adding the newly calculated value for $c_3$ to the previous value for $c_2$; and finally the first equation says you update $f$ for the point $x+h$ by adding the newly calculated value for $c_2$.

Comment: Ah, very clever. And so for any polynomial, there will be a level at which the backward finite differences are constant, and so you can always compute the next step by adding on the differences at each level.

Comment: @Jolyon Exactly. For a degree $n$ polynomial the constant value will be $n! Ah^n$ where $A$ is the leading coefficient. This algorithm is the reverse of those tables where you compute successive differences between values $f(1), f(2), f(3),\ldots$ of a polynomial and eventually arrive at a row of constants.